# Why do I get an Access Violation in atio6axx.dll when calling glBindBuffer?

Tags: c, opengl, dll, amd-processor, pelles-c

### Leading up to the problem:

Learning about OpenGL using C, by making a (supposedly easy) tile-based game of my own design. Originally I was drawing only ~10 triangles or so for testing, and I set up the buffer data and indices like so:

```
const float vertexPositions[] = {
      -1.0f, -0.8f, //0
      -1.0f, -1.0f, //1

      -0.8f, -0.8f, //2
      -0.8f, -1.0f, //3

      -0.8f, -0.8f, //2
      -0.8f, -1.0f, //3

      -0.6f, -0.8f, //4
      -0.6f, -1.0f, //5

      -0.6f, -0.8f, //4
      -0.6f, -1.0f, //5

      -0.4f, -0.8f, //6
      -0.4f, -1.0f, //7

      -0.4f, -0.8f, //6
      -0.4f, -1.0f, //7

      -0.2f, -0.8f, //8
      -0.2f, -1.0f, //9

      -0.2f, -0.8f, //8
      -0.2f, -1.0f, //9

       0.0f, -0.8f, //10
       0.0f, -1.0f, //11

       0.0f, -0.8f, //10
       0.0f, -1.0f, //11

/////////////////////////////////// Texture coords:
       0.0f,  1.0f, //0
       0.0f,  0.0f, //1

       1.0f,  1.0f, //2
       1.0f,  0.0f, //3

       0.0f,  1.0f, //2
       0.0f,  0.0f, //3

       1.0f,  1.0f, //4
       1.0f,  0.0f, //5

       0.0f,  1.0f, //4
       0.0f,  0.0f, //5

       1.0f,  1.0f, //6
       1.0f,  0.0f, //7

       0.0f,  1.0f, //6
       0.0f,  0.0f, //7

       1.0f,  1.0f, //8
       1.0f,  0.0f, //9

       0.0f,  1.0f, //8
       0.0f,  0.0f, //9

       1.0f,  1.0f, //10
       1.0f,  0.0f, //11

       0.0f,  1.0f, //10
       0.0f,  0.0f, //11

const GLubyte indices[] = {
      0, 1, 2, 
      3, 2, 1,

      4, 5, 6,
      7, 6, 5, 

      8, 9, 10,
      11, 10, 9,

      12, 13, 14,
      15, 14, 13,

      16, 17, 18,
      19, 18, 17,
};
```

Since I would need a lot more triangles to make more triangles, I decided to automate it (also, the values are in pixels instead of screen/viewport co-ordinates as i intend to use some matrices in my shader):

```
float vertexPositions[6400]; //Declared globally outside the function

int blah()
{
      int count = 0, texture_start;



      for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
      {
            for (int x = 0; x < 21; x++)
            {
                  vertexPositions[count++] = x * 32.0f;
                  vertexPositions[count++] = (y + 1) * 32.0f;

                  vertexPositions[count++] = x * 32.0f;                  
                  vertexPositions[count++] = y * 32.0f;

                  if (x > 0 && x < 20)
                  {
                        vertexPositions[count++] = x * 32.0f;
                        vertexPositions[count++] = (y + 1) * 32.0f;

                        vertexPositions[count++] = x * 32.0f;                  
                        vertexPositions[count++] = y * 32.0f;
                  }
            }
      }

      texture_start = count;

      for (int z = 0; z < 400; z++)
      {
                  vertexPositions[count++] = 0.0f;
                  vertexPositions[count++] = 1.0f;

                  vertexPositions[count++] = 0.0f;
                  vertexPositions[count++] = 0.0f;

                  vertexPositions[count++] = 1.0f;
                  vertexPositions[count++] = 1.0f;

                  vertexPositions[count++] = 1.0f;
                  vertexPositions[count++] = 0.0f;
      }

      return 0;
}
```

Note, I haven't automated the indices because I wanted to make sure I could get the exact same triangles from this new data.

### The Issue:

I repeatedly get access violations on *certain* GL calls. If I step manually between breakpoints it always fails when it reaches `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);`.

If I have one breakpoint *on* this line and one breakpoint *after* this line it skips(ignores? silently fails on?) the lines in between and breaks when it reaches `GLuint fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);` inside the `myProgram = CreateProgram();` call (which is surprising since my vertex shader is created immediately previous with an identical call and works fine).

```
GLvoid InitGL(GLvoid)
{
      blah(); <----where i initialize my vertex data
      FnLdInit();
      GetBitmap();

      //char * glVer = (char *)glGetString(GL_VERSION);
      //char * glSLV = (char *)glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);

      glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
      glClearDepth(1.0f);
      glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
      glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);      ---------------------------//~BREAKPOINT HERE!~

      glGenBuffers(1, &positionBufferObject);
      errort = glGetError();

      glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject); 
      //errort = glGetError();
      glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), (const float *)vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
      //errort = glGetError();
      glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
      //errort = glGetError();

      myProgram = CreateProgram();   -------------------------//~BREAKPOINT HERE!~

}
```

All glGetError()'s return 0, which the spec says it means: there is no problem or glGetError had its own error.

No matter where it breaks though, the call stack pelles C shows me when it breaks is 'atio6axx.dll; DrvPresentBuffers() +163B7B' and it is *always* here:

[image: The source of my raaaaaaaage]

I recently installed the latest Catalyst update for my Radeon HD 6850. I can find nothing regarding memory limitations in regards to the GPU/vertex buffer objects/etc, and I doubt ~25KB of data would break much of anything at all. I have a feeling it's not an OpenGL issue, and rather something in the way I'm implementing my code or a limitation/memory issue I'm unfamiliar with.

[Poster #20](http://www.daz3d.com/forums/viewthread/9471/P15/) on this site has a similar problem, but it seems to be connected to a program failure, not code (and I think it happened before the latest drivers came out, even though it was posted Oct 11th). `GetBitmap()` makes use of glBindTexture and other calls with no problems.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834164/access-violation-writing-location) seems like the most obvious, but the only thing I changed from my old algorithm to my new is the automation of my data creation. There are no pointers involved, and I even cast to a `const float *`, which the compiler didn't even warn me was necessary.

Am I looking in the wrong places for the solution to a simple problem? I'll try to explain my code/add more of it if needed, just ask. I'd really rather not write out ~6400 values or more by hand.

**Edit #1**: After some other tests it seems this error occurs even with the old implementation. I must not have compiled it for a while (been working on the shaders, which are separate files). I am *very* confused.

**Edit #2**: Some more code. This is the only function that occurs before InitGL, and is the one that calls InitGl. :

```
bool CreateGLWindow(char* title, int width, int height, int bits, bool fullscreenflag)
{
      GLuint PixelFormat;
      WNDCLASS wc;
      DWORD dwExStyle;
      DWORD dwStyle;

      RECT WindowRect;
      WindowRect.left = (long)0;
      WindowRect.right = (long)width;
      WindowRect.top = (long)0;
      WindowRect.bottom = (long)height;

      fullscreen = fullscreenflag;

      hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

      wc.style = CS_HREDRAW |CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
      wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) WndProc;
      wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
      wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
      wc.hInstance = hInstance;
      wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
      wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
      wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
      wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
      wc.lpszClassName = "OpenGL";

      if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
      {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to register the window class", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

            return FALSE;
      }

      if (fullscreen)
      {
            int changeresult;
            //char msg[100];
            DISPLAY_DEVICE disp;
            DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;
            int dw;

            memset(&disp, 0, sizeof(disp));
            memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));

            disp.cb = sizeof(disp);


            if (!(EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, 0, &disp, 0)))
            {
                  return 1;
            }


            dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);

            //ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS
            if (!(EnumDisplaySettings(disp.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dmScreenSettings)))
            {
                  dw = GetLastError();
            }

            dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = width; //enable this in real
            dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = height; //enable this in real

            changeresult = ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN);

            //dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = width;
            //dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = height;
            //dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = bits;
            dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

            if (changeresult != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
            {
                  if (MessageBox(NULL, "Use window mode?", "GL", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION) == IDYES)
                  {
                        fullscreen = FALSE;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                        return FALSE;
                  }
            }
      }

      if (fullscreen)
      {
            dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
            dwStyle = WS_POPUP;
            ShowCursor(FALSE);
      }
      else
      {
            dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
            dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
      }

      AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowRect, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);

      if(!(hWnd = CreateWindowEx(   dwExStyle,
                                    "OpenGL",
                                    title,
                                    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | dwStyle,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    WindowRect.right - WindowRect.left,
                                    WindowRect.bottom - WindowRect.top,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL,
                                    hInstance,
                                    NULL)))
      {
            KillGLWindow();
            MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation error", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

            return FALSE;
      }

      static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd=                  // pfd Tells Windows How We Want Things To Be
      {
          sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),                  // Size Of This Pixel Format Descriptor
          1,                              // Version Number
          PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |            // Format Must Support Window
          PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |            // Format Must Support OpenGL
          PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,               // Must Support Double Buffering
          PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                  // Request An RGBA Format
          0,                           // Select Our Color Depth
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,               // Color Bits Ignored
          0,                              // No Alpha Buffer
          0,                              // Shift Bit Ignored
          0,                              // No Accumulation Buffer
          0, 0, 0, 0,                     // Accumulation Bits Ignored
          16,                             // 16Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer)
          0,                              // No Stencil Buffer
          0,                              // No Auxiliary Buffer
          PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                 // Main Drawing Layer
          0,                              // Reserved
          0, 0, 0                         // Layer Masks Ignored
      };
      pfd.cColorBits = bits;

      if (!(hDC = GetDC(hWnd)))
      {
            KillGLWindow();
            MessageBox(NULL, "Can't create a GL device context", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

            return FALSE;
      }

      if (!(PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd)))
      {
            KillGLWindow();
            MessageBox(NULL, "Can't find a suitable pixelformat", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

            return FALSE;
      }

      if (!SetPixelFormat(hDC, PixelFormat, &pfd))
      {
            KillGLWindow();
            MessageBox(NULL, "Can't set the pixel format", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

            return FALSE;
      }

      if (!(hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC)))
      {
            KillGLWindow();
            MessageBox(NULL, "Can't create a GL rendering context", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

            return FALSE;
      }

      if (!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC))
      {
            KillGLWindow();
            MessageBox(NULL, "Can't activate the GL rendering context", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

            return FALSE;
      }

      ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
      SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
      SetFocus(hWnd);

      InitGL();
      ResizeGLScene(width, height);

      //char * glVer = (char *)glGetString(GL_VERSION);
      //char * glSLV = (char *)glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);

      return TRUE;
}
```

FnLdInit is where I hook up all the extensions:

```
void FnLdInit(void)
{
      HINSTANCE hGLLIB = NULL;
      hGLLIB = LoadLibrary("opengl32.dll");

      glActiveTexture                     = (PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glActiveTexture");
      glAttachShader                      = (PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glAttachShader");
      glBindBuffer                        = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBindBuffer");
      glBufferData                        = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBufferData");
      glCompileShader                     = (PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glCompileShader");
      glCreateProgram                     = (PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glCreateProgram");
      glCreateShader                      = (PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glCreateShader");
      glDeleteShader                      = (PFNGLDELETESHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glDeleteShader");
      glDetachShader                      = (PFNGLDETACHSHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glDetachShader");
      glDisableVertexAttribArray          = (PFNGLDISABLEVERTEXATTRIBARRAYPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glDisableVertexAttribArray");
      glEnableVertexAttribArray           = (PFNGLENABLEVERTEXATTRIBARRAYPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
      glGenBuffers                        = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
      glGetShaderInfoLog                  = (PFNGLGETSHADERINFOLOGPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGetShaderInfoLog");
      glGetShaderiv                       = (PFNGLGETSHADERIVPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGetShaderiv");
      glGetUniformfv                      = (PFNGLGETUNIFORMFVPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGetUniformfv");
      glGetUniformLocation                = (PFNGLGETUNIFORMLOCATIONPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGetUniformLocation");
      glLinkProgram                       = (PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glLinkProgram");
      glShaderSource                      = (PFNGLSHADERSOURCEPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glShaderSource");
      glUniform1i                         = (PFNGLUNIFORM1IPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glUniform1i");
      glUniform2f                         = (PFNGLUNIFORM2FPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glUniform2f");
      glUseProgram                        = (PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glUseProgram");
      glVertexAttribPointer               = (PFNGLVERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glVertexAttribPointer");

      glBindTexture           = (PFNGLBINDTEXTUREPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glBindTexture");
      glClear                 = (PFNGLCLEARPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glClear");
      glClearColor            = (PFNGLCLEARCOLORPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glClearColor");
      glClearDepth            = (PFNGLCLEARDEPTHPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glClearDepth");
      glDepthFunc             = (PFNGLDEPTHFUNCPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glDepthFunc");
      glDrawArrays            = (PFNGLDRAWARRAYSPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glDrawArrays");
      glEnable                = (PFNGLENABLEPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glEnable");
      glGenTextures           = (PFNGLGENTEXTURESPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glGenTextures");
      glTexImage2D            = (PFNGLTEXIMAGE2DPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glTexImage2D");
      glTexParameteri         = (PFNGLTEXPARAMETERIPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glTexParameteri");
      glViewport              = (PFNGLVIEWPORTPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glViewport");
      glDrawElements          = (PFNGLDRAWELEMENTSPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glDrawElements");
      glGetError              = (PFNGLGETERRORPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glGetError");
      glGetString             = (PFNGLGETSTRINGPROC)GetProcAddress(hGLLIB, "glGetString");
}
```

And here's GetBitmap():

```
int GetBitmap(void)
{
      char        * bmBuffer, * pxPtr;
      FILE        * bmFile;
      //FILE * result;
      GLuint      texture;

      int         bmSize, 
                  dataOffset, 
                  dibSize, 
                  bmWidthPx, 
                  bmHeightPx,
                  bmCompression,
                  dataSize,
                  dataHorRes,
                  dataVerRes,
                  paletteNumClrs,
                  importantClrs,

                  bmBytesPerPixel = 3, //Default -> RGB

                  totalBytesPerRow,
                  pixelBytesPerRow,
                  padCount = 0;

      short int   bmClrPlane, bmBPP;
      char        bmChar0, bmChar1;
      //char msgData[100];

      bmFile = fopen("multisquare.bmp", "rb");
      if (bmFile == NULL)
      {
            return 1;
      }

      bmChar0 = fgetc(bmFile);
      bmChar1 = fgetc(bmFile);
      if (bmChar0 != 'B' || bmChar1 != 'M')
      {
            return 2;
      }

      //sprintf(msgData, "%c%c", bmChar0, bmChar1);
      //MessageBox(NULL, msgData, NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

      bmSize = Get4Bytes(bmFile);

      //Skip 4 bytes. These bytes are application specific,
      //and generally unused.
      if (fseek(bmFile, 4, SEEK_CUR) != 0)
      {
            return 3;
      }

      dataOffset = Get4Bytes(bmFile);

      dibSize = Get4Bytes(bmFile);

      //Replace 'if dibSize' check with case statement
      //which branches to functions for different sized 
      //DIBHeaders.
      //
      //
      if (dibSize != 40)
      {
            return 4;
      }

      bmWidthPx = Get4Bytes(bmFile);
      bmHeightPx = Get4Bytes(bmFile); //Later -> handle negative = top->bottom.

      bmClrPlane = Get2Bytes(bmFile); //Must always be 1 anyways, consider removing this and skipping 2 bytes.
      bmBPP = Get2Bytes(bmFile);

      if (bmBPP == 24)
      {
            bmBytesPerPixel = 3;
      }

      bmCompression = Get4Bytes(bmFile);
      //Handle other compressions at some later time.
      if (bmCompression != 0)
      {
            return 5;
      }

      //Can use this to allocate appropriate memory space.
      dataSize = Get4Bytes(bmFile);

      //Resolutions doesn't seem too important atm.
      dataHorRes = Get4Bytes(bmFile);
      dataVerRes = Get4Bytes(bmFile);

      //Will probably both be 0. Irrelevant atm.
      paletteNumClrs = Get4Bytes(bmFile);
      importantClrs = Get4Bytes(bmFile);

      bmBuffer = (char *) calloc(dataSize, sizeof(char)); //Space allocated.

      fseek(bmFile, dataOffset, SEEK_SET);

      //Ex: 10 pixels * 3 bytes/pixel = 30 bytes
      //    30 + 3 = 33 -> 0010 0001
      //    Right shift 2: 0000 1000  -> These operations round to nearest
      //    Shift left 2:  0010 0000  -> multiple of 4.
      //    32 bytes to reach 4byte multiple
      //    So 30 bytes for 10 pixles plus 2 extra bytes of padding, per row.
      pixelBytesPerRow = bmWidthPx * bmBytesPerPixel;
      totalBytesPerRow = ((pixelBytesPerRow + bmBytesPerPixel) >> 2) << 2;
      padCount = totalBytesPerRow - pixelBytesPerRow;

      pxPtr = bmBuffer;

      switch(padCount)
      {
            case 0:
            {
                  for (int A = 0; A <= bmHeightPx; A++)
                  {
                        /*
                        for (int B = 0; B <= bmWidthPx; B++)
                        {

                              *(pxPtr + 2) = fgetc(bmFile);
                              *(pxPtr + 1) = fgetc(bmFile);
                              *pxPtr       = fgetc(bmFile);

                        }
                        */
                        fread(pxPtr, 1, pixelBytesPerRow, bmFile);
                        pxPtr += totalBytesPerRow;
                  }

                  break;
            }
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            {
                  for (int A = 0; A <= bmHeightPx; A++)
                  {
                        /*
                        for (int B = 0; B <= bmWidthPx; B++)
                        {

                              *(pxPtr + 2) = fgetc(bmFile);
                              *(pxPtr + 1) = fgetc(bmFile);
                              *pxPtr       = fgetc(bmFile);

                        }
                        */
                        fread(pxPtr, 1, pixelBytesPerRow, bmFile);

                        if (fseek(bmFile, padCount, SEEK_CUR) != 0)
                        {
                              return 3;
                        }

                        pxPtr += totalBytesPerRow;

                  }

                  break;
            }
            default:
            //Shouldn't get here
            break;
      }
      //result = fopen("test.txt","w");
      //fwrite(bmBuffer, 1, dataSize , result);
      //fclose(result);
      fclose(bmFile);

      glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
      glGenTextures(1, &texture);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

      glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,   /*Type of texture*/
                   0,               /*Level of Detail number*/
                   GL_RGB,          /*Internal format*/
                   bmWidthPx,       /*Width in texels(pixels?)*/
                   bmHeightPx,      /*Height in texels(pixels?)*/
                   0,               /*Border. Must be 0 (probably only for 2D)*/
                   GL_BGR,          /*Format, of the data the texture will be created from*/
                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,/*Data type of the pixel data*/
                   bmBuffer);       /*Pointer to the image data to create the texture from*/

      //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

      free(bmBuffer);


      return 0;
}
```

**Edit #3**: Unistalled Catalyst 12.10 and all associated drivers. Reinstalled 12.8. Same problem, but now it happens on GenBuffers. Odd.

**Edit #4**: I tried making my project 32bit, and compiling it. I get the exact same problem, though for some reason Pelles C is not labeling the LIBs (it just says "untitled" anytime it mentions one) so I can only assume the 32bit lib AMD provides is also failing (as atio6axx.dll/.lib is not loaded). I have a feeling this problem won't have any real solution because it seems to stem from the drivers, not my code. After searching and seeing related problems like [this](http://www.townswiki.com/wiki/Known_Issues_and_Workarounds#ATI_Driver_Issue), it seems like there isn't really a client-side solution.

**Edit #5**: Another issue, which I did not notice before because the program never gave me an access violation at this point, is that the code will reach `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` and suddenly skip all the lines afterwords and exits the function. By removing this line the next lines are executed. `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` is from `atio6axx.dll` while all the other commands are from `OPENGL32.dll`, so it seems to have narrowed it down. What's odd is there is no access violation at this point, just the odd skipping.

I suppose no one can see a reason for any of this happening? I've even installed the *beta* Catalyst drivers, which has a version atio6axx.dll that is dated 15\11\2012 (last thursday). So up-to-date drivers are not an issue. I've even tried every driver version since Catalyst 12.4 (current is 12.10, and this program ran with 12.8). At a loss, and even a new program runs into the same problems.

Comment: Programs crashing on calls to AMD drivers is a huge issue and hard to solve! This "extraordinarily narrow situation" is a very important one to many people with AMD cards. I have an HD 7700 card that I haven't been able to get to work for months with the same error when the same code works on my laptop. Please reopen question!

Answer (score 2):

The code for the vertex positions seems good and does not appear to write outside the bounds of the array. The access violation you see is probably caused by r11 being invalid.
OpenGL driver code is usually multithreaded so it might be possible that you only see that error when a worker thread tries to access that bad buffer. Which could account for the strange behavior you are seeing in the locality of the failure.

Make sure that the buffer is not freed before the GPU is done with it, that you pass the proper sizes, etc.

I'm afraid you'll have to paste more code for us to be able to assist you further.

Also providing us with the value of r11 might help.

Comment: r11 = 00000001479287A0. I'm not sure which buffer you're talking about being freed. vertexPositions[6400] is global and on the stack, not the heap. Could you clarify? I'll see about posting more code.

Comment: How about throwing it up on github? I've downloaded Pelles C would be on for joining in figuring out.

Comment: @Rob: I've never actually used github, but that doesn't sound like a bad idea. I'll let you know if/when i put it up there. Revision control could certainly help me...

Comment: @Rob: Alright, i have it here: https://github.com/Hydronium/TimeSink. Also Nicholas I added 3 more code blocks in my second edit to the original post. Hopefully that's enough (but now it's all on github too...in one giant file).